# Python - word count using google custom search engine

Tags: python, google-search

I'm using python to search using a custom google engine. I'm able to find the total number of results for the search using results["searchInformation"]["totalResults"]. How would I count the number of times a specific word appears in the search?

Answer (score 0):

Investigating the parameters that the API does return after a search I’ve not found anything similar to an automatic word count within the accessible fields. However I’ve found a workaround that might work for you; you can do a manual routine for word count from the results dump file.

As the file is limited by the maximum amount of pages you can search in, I recommend you to play with the maximum number that works for you (mine was 11, it varies from search to search).

If you dump these results in a json file, you will be able to do the word count executing the following code (it is in linux shell, although you can also implement it in python) :

```
cat data.json | tr -s "," "\n" | grep -e "title" -e "snippet" | grep -c '<your word>'
```

Where:

- ‘data.json’: is the dump file with the search results from the API.
- ‘tr -s "," "\n"’: does a line separation for every of the listed lines.
- ‘grep -e "title" -e "snippet"’: filters the lines with  “title” or “snippet” only (title and description of the the results, no metadata)
- ‘grep -c ''’: does a count of the introduced word